# when is it appropriate to use double prime for inches in measurements

Tags: measuring-units, symbols

What is the correct usage?

- 10 × 10″
- 10″ × 10″

That is, is the double prime supposed to be on the first number or is it assumed to be the same as the second number when conveying measurements in inches?

Comment: I don't have any references, but personally, I'd put it on each, so there is no ambiguity. The first version could almost be saying that you need a *quantity* 10 of 10" items.

Answer (score 5):

Almost all of 800 written instances of [**4 by 4 posts**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%224+by+4+posts%22) in Google Books will reflect OP's context.

If you glance through them you'll see that although most don't have *any* "double primes", those that do always seem to include it on *both* measurements.

In this respect the written convention doesn't precisely reflect *spoken* usage, where it wouldn't be particularly unusual to ask for a [*Four by four **inch** post*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22four%20by%20four%20inch%20post%22).